# If the topic doesn't need anything else to move on to the next phase, why hasn't it?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, area-51

[Area 51 bug http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/8774/area51bug.png](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications)

[This](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications) says that it needs nothing to move on to the next level.  Why hasn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's in beta and that's not ready yet

See Joel's comment [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications)

> Semi-official announcement: It's going to be a few more days before the code for the commit phase is ready. In the meantime, you can still vote for your favorite on-topic and off-topic questions, so that when we get to the commit phase, the top 10 on-topic and top 10 off-topic questions do a good job of describing and delineating the site

Answer (score 4):

We're rolling things out in stages.  The commitment phase will be rolled out later this week or early next week.

Answer (score 2):

The commit phase has not been completed yet:

> ※※※ Semi-official announcement: It's going to be a few more days before the code for the commit phase is ready. In the meantime, you can still vote for your favorite on-topic and off-topic questions, so that when we get to the commit phase, the top 10 on-topic and top 10 off-topic questions do a good job of describing and delineating the site. – Joel Spolsky♦

Also, Area 51 is still in Beta. It's always possible that the process will have to be tweaked to get better results. We don't want to advance sites too quickly while everything is still under development.

Also, Area 51 has not even been announced, yet, publicly. We don't want to rush a bunch of sites out the back door when only a small number of people have had their input.

There's no rush. Let this stuff bake for awhile.

Comment: Why did you steal my answer Robert? Why?

Comment: @Juan Manuel - It's that damned unicorn in your Gravatar. It made me do it.

Comment: Those unicorns.  One day... One day I _will make them pay!_